# How can I find percentile $P_{10}$ and $P_{90}$ for Normal Distribution with Mean as $100$ and Standard Deviation as $3$?

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution, gaussian

How can I find percentile $P_{10}$ and $P_{90}$ for Normal Distribution with Mean as $100$ and Standard Deviation as $3$?

Example
[image]

I don't understand from where the $-1.28$ come. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please, provide more information.

Comment: You appear to be using the sampling distribution for mean with sample size 25. You are then looking a percentage points for the standard normal after standardising by subtracting mean and dividing by standard error. As has been said missing a lot of detail.

Answer (score 3):

-1.28 is the 10th percentile of the standard normal distribution.

If you're working with the distribution $\mathsf{Norm}(\mu=100,\sigma=3)$
then you can you can find its percentiles by starting with the percentiles
of a standard normal distribution.

The formula for the 10th percentile of $\mathsf{Norm}(\mu=100,\sigma=3)$ is 
$$\mu + (-1.28)\sigma = 100 - 1.28(3) = 96.16.$$

From R statistical software, here are percentiles 10, 20, ..., 90, first
of standard normal $\mathsf{Norm}(\mu=0, \sigma=1),$ which you can get (to 2 decimal places) from a printed table of the CDF of standard normal, and 
second of $\mathsf{Norm}(\mu=100,\sigma=3),$ which you can get from the former by using the formula above:

```
p = seq(10, 90, by=10);  p
[1] 10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90

qnorm(p/100, 0, 1)
[1] -1.2815516 -0.8416212 -0.5244005 -0.2533471
[5]  0.0000000  0.2533471  0.5244005  0.8416212
[9]  1.2815516

qnorm(p/100, 100, 3)
[1]  96.15535  97.47514  98.42680  99.23996
[5] 100.00000 100.76004 101.57320 102.52486
[9] 103.84465
```

*Notes:* In R, `qnorm` is the 'inverse Cumulative Distribution Function' (inverse CDF),
which is sometimes called the 'quantile function'.

If you have
a statistical calculator, maybe you can figure out how to get percentiles from it.

If you are using a printed normal table, try this: Look for the closest
number in the *body* of the table to .50, .60, ..., .90. Then find the
percentile value from the *margin* of the table. For percentiles with
negative values, you may have to use the symmetry of the normal distribution.

'Percentiles' are a particular kind of quantiles (based on 1/100). Other particular kinds of quantile that you may encounter later are quartiles (based on 1/4), quintiles (based on 1/5), and deciles (based on 1/10). The lower quartile is the 25th percentile, the median is the 50th percentile.